# What kind of post type structure do I need to manage a list of ranked skills?

Tags: custom-post-types, management

I'm currently creating a portfolio site that requires me to manage a list of skills.
I want to manage these skills in a clean overview in the backend.
The list of skills consists of two entries per skill:

1. The skill name (ie. Singing)
2. The skill rank (ie. 7)

I'm having trouble thinking of a clean method to manage these skills.

So far I came up with creating a category 'skills' and using the Name of a post as the skill name and a custom meta key 'skill_rank' that has the skill rank.

I'd much rather prefer a single view for the management though.

Is there a way of creating a single custom post type where I can manage all these skills (there are probably around 10+) in a single view/post?

I prefer coding over plugins.

Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Comment: How about Post Type "Skills" with Post Meta "Skill Rank"? Being a number it would be easy to query and sort on, you can even create custom post type columns to show the Skill Rank in the admin panel.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee That's awesome. I had no idea you could manage post columns.
That gives me the overview, now all I need is a quick edit function for that column.

Comment: I can't say I've ever used it but there's a [`quick_edit_custom_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/quick_edit_custom_box) action you may be able to use, good luck!